# c++ - throwing custom null pointer exception

Tags: c++, exception, this

Is there an easy way to throw custom null pointer exception in c++?
My idea was to redefine `this` pointer, but it has 3 problems:

1. Not using `this` throws standard Acces Violation Exception
2. Pointer is checked every time it is used
3. Visual studio show this as `InteliSense` error (compilable) (do not know what other compilers do)

   ```
   #include <iostream>
   #define this (this != nullptr ? (*this) : throw "NullPointerException")

   class Obj
   {
   public:
       int x;
       void Add(const Obj& obj)
       {
           this.x += obj.x; // throws "NullPointerException"
                   //x = obj.x;  // throws Access Violation Exception
       }
   };


   void main()
   {
       Obj *o = new Obj();
       Obj *o2 = nullptr;
       try
       {
           (*o2).Add(*o);
       }
       catch (char *exception)
       {
           std::cout << exception;
       }
       getchar();
   }
   ```

Comment: Huh? Do you get a compile error or what?

Comment: No copile error. Program works as expected exception is thrown. Visual studio's intelisence (code assist) show that it is invalid use but do not prevent from compiling.

Comment: My personal policy is that re-defining keywords is the wild wild west.  Good luck!

Comment: g++-4.6.1 error: `error: using temporary as lvalue`

Comment: Umm, `this` can never, ever be NULL unless your code is horribly, catastrophically broken. `this != nullptr` is the same as `true`.

Comment: Redefining keywords is illegal, and the `this` pointer cannot be null in a correct program. The compiler knows that and can optimize away the test. Bad idea.

Comment: Defining a macro that overrides a keyword is illegal.

Comment: Side not: "A String" is a `char const*` your catch block shoudl be modified.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Since `this` can never, ever be `nullptr`, compilers are free to treat `this != nullptr` the same as `true`. What you're trying to do fundamentally doesn't make sense. You can't use exceptions to catch undefined behavior. The only way `this` can be `nullptr` is through undefined behavior.

```
Obj *o2 = nullptr;
try
{
    (*o2).Add(*o);
}
```

Dereferencing a `nullptr` is undefined behavior (8.3.2). This is trying to use an exception to catch undefined behavior. Fundamentally, you cannot do that in C++.

For one obvious reason this is undefined, consider this:

```
class Foo
{
   public:
   Foo { ; }
   virtual void func() = 0;
};

class Bar : public Foo
{
   public:
   Bar() { ; }
   virtual void func() { some_code() }
};

class Baz : public foo
{
    public:
    Baz() { ; }
    virtual void func() { some_other_code(); }
}

...

Foo * j = nullptr;
j->func(); // Uh oh, which func?
```

Comment: If OP had done `o2->Add(*o);` then that would be defined, right?  And its valid in that case to check `this` inside the function?  (Not a sane thing to do nonetheless, but valid.)

Comment: No, `o2` is a `nullptr`. `a->b;` is the same as `(*a).b`. So a `nullptr` is still dereferenced. See 9.3.1.

Comment: You made a good point, but I've  got one extra question.Does dereference occur when non-virtual method is called ?

Comment: Yes. Any time you do `*a` or `a->`, you have dereferenced `a`.

Comment: I may be wrong but doesnot compiler replaces non-virtual methods with address? It that case dereference did not occure in when you use o2->Add(*o)

Comment: That's not how C or C++ work. The rules are in the standard. The compiler is not required to make this case work or to make it break because the standard prohibits you from putting the compiler in this case at all. If you dereference a `nullptr`, your code is broken. What it does is dependent on what the compiler happens to do. And the next version of the compiler might happen to do something else. It might even break with the same program but a newer library, OS, or even CPU. The only sane strategy for dealing with UB is to completely avoid it.